# div resize with browser

Tags: javascript, resize

I'm trying to build a simple image viewer that resizes with the browser width/height. I believe I'm almost there. However, I need a hint on how to finish this. Here is the code. I didn't want to use jquery because I'm trying to keep this as simple and as light as possible.

Thank you,
MK

```
<style type="text/css">
body {
    background-color: #999;
}
#fullscreenPhoto {
    border: thin solid #F00;
}
</style>

<body onresize="resizeImage()">
<div onload="resizeImage()" margin="0" border="0" id="fullscreenPhoto">
    <img  src="resizeImage.jpg" width="100%" >
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var divResize = document.getElementById('fullscreenPhoto');

function resizeImage()
{
    var window_height = document.body.clientHeight
    var window_width  = document.body.clientWidth

    var image_height  = divResize.offsetHeight
    var image_width   = divResize.offsetWidth

    var height_ratio  = image_height / window_height
    var width_ratio   = image_width / window_width

    if (height_ratio > width_ratio)
    {
        divResize.style.width  = "auto"
        divResize.style.height = "100%"
    }
    else
    {
        divResize.style.width  = "100%"
        divResize.style.height = "auto"
    }
}
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: What exactly are you missing?

Comment: I'm not sure. Is this working for you? I added a solid red boarder around div for testing. The div doesn't seem to resized with the browser height.

Answer (score 0):

How about setting maxHeight and maxWidth instead of width and height where it needs to be 100%. That way you may not even need to specify 'auto'

So in your example it would be

```
if (height_ratio > width_ratio)
{
    divResize.style.maxHeight = "100%"
}
else
{
    divResize.style.maxWidth  = "100%"
}
```

Comment: No luck with that fix. Is it working for you? One thing I am wondering is.. is it possible to resize by browser height?

Comment: oops, maxWidth and maxHeight are properties that have effect only on block-level elements or on elements with absolute or fixed position. Maybe setting the 'position' for divResize to fixed or absolute might work?

Comment: I ve added one more answer which achieves what you want with pure CSS (no JavaScript)

Answer (score 0):

The `div` is never loaded. It is a primitive HTML type. You have to put the `onload` statement in the image tag. And as the image is within the Div, you don't have to resize it. It gets stretched by the image.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here s another answer altogether (based on your comment on wanting to set the 'stretch' based on 'height'... this one doesnt event use JavaScript! Just make sure the html and body CSS property height is set to 100% and then set the image CSS height property to 100%

HTML:

```
<div  margin="0" border="0" id="fullscreenPhoto">
    <img src="http://www.walmik.com/wp-content/themes/spring/images/motif.png" >
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
#fullscreenPhoto img {position:fixed; top:0; left:0; width:auto; height:100%;}
```

And finally, here s a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/XwBxh/

And here s a small addition in case you want to support IE6:

```
html { overflow-y: hidden; }
body { overflow-y: auto; }
#fullscreenPhoto img { position:absolute; z-index:-1; }
```